# Vertices jump away when scaling or transforming

Tags: vertices

I select it as normal
[image]
And then this happens.
[image]

I've had this happen to me a few times before. It seems to just show up when it feels like it.
Any idea what this could be? Thanks.

Comment: hello, hard to say, maybe share a video or share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Here you go https://pasteall.org/blend/1899270feacc4fcca7f7246b0632689f

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Its useful when you share screenshots to include the window decorations, if someone had seen the X axis mirror on in the window decoration they may have been able to answer without seeing the blend file.

Answer (score 1):

it's the *Topology Mirror* option in the *Options* panel, under *Mirror XYZ*, I'm not sure how this option is supposed to work, maybe use a *Mirror* modifier or sometimes *Mesh > Symmetrize* instead? If you *Mesh > Symmetrize*, the *Mirror XYZ* alone will work.

[image]

Comment: That was the fix, thank you!